# Remove trailing slash using .htaccess for multiple urls

Tags: .htaccess

Last week I have posted something similar like the question whereas I wanted to know how to remove trailing slash using .htaccess for a particular page and rest pages will be redirect with trailing slash.

```
abc.com/demo/ should redirect to abc.com/demo
```

And I got the solution as following.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/demo/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^demo/$ /demo [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

But now I need for multiple urls. eg. demo2, demo3, demo4 etc, so in those scenario how will be the code, need suggestion.

```
abc.com/demo2/ redirect to abc.com/demo2
abc.com/demo3/ redirect to abc.com/demo3
abc.com/demo4/ redirect to abc.com/demo4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove traling slash from multiple uris ,you could a  regular expression  capture-group that matches more then one values at one time something like the following :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(demo1|demo2|demo3|demo4)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule /$ /%1 [L,R]
```

The `%1` in the above rule is a RewriteCond backreference and it holds the value matched inside
`(demo1|demo2|......)` regex pattern ie: `demo1` .

You can use the following htaccess to remove and add traling slashes .

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove traling slash from spacifc uris
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(demo1|demo2|demo3|demo4)/$ [NC]
RewriteRule /$ /%1 [L,R]
# add traling slash to other uris except the spacifc ones
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(demo1|demo2|demo3|demo4)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.